# Retrieve Anonymous Ancestor Axioms through OWL API

Tags: owl, protege, owl-api

I need to retrieve the SubClassOf axioms for an anonymous ancestor of the given class. For example:

```
 Class Person is a subclass of 'hasName some Name'.
 Class Man is a subclass of Person.
```

Then I need to be able to retrieve `hasName some Name` on the class `Man` by accessing the axioms provided to the class `Man` by its anonymous ancestor.

Now I could obviously do so with recursion, however I wanted to know if there is another way through OWL API by which I could access this information. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately no - the OWL API methods require you to iterate through all super classes, and OWLReasoner - which has methods to retrieve all super classes - will not return anonymous super classes, only named ones.
(It has to - retrieving /all/ anonymous super classes is a non terminating task for a reasoner)